# writing explicit interface I1 c=new customer();

Tags: c#

How can we use derived c=new parent as in main function. like in this it is written that I1 c=new customer.But I1 is derived how it can be written I1 c=new customer.I1 is derivative and customer is parent

```cs
using System;

interface I1
{
    void print();

}

interface I2
{
    void print();
}

public class customer : I1, I2
{
    public void print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("USING PRINT OF INTERFACE i1");


    }
    void I2.print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("USING PRINT OF INTERFACE i2");


    }

}

namespace explicitinterfaces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            I1 c = new customer();
            c.print();

        }
    }
}
```

it should be customer c =new customer();.

Comment: I think you need to read about abstraction and interface!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Format your question for example.

Comment: Try it with `I2 c = new customer();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much I understood from your question that you are confused by this  `I1 c = new customer();` line of code , it basically means you are creating a reference of interface I1 and assigning the object of class customer to this reference , now in simple words it means that from reference I1 you can call only the methods declare inside interface I1. one more thing to add - you use word derive and parent , these words are used when there is an inheritance between classes , in your code its interface so you don't inherit the interface but you implement the interface